# редактор цветов фото на filter css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Сделал редактор цветов на js при помощи filter css. Все работает относительно нормально, но при скачивание фото фильтры не применяются, каким образом можно это реализовать?

img.style.filter = sepia(${sepia.value}%) blur(${blur.value / 10}px) opacity(${opacity.value}%) grayscale(${grayscale.value}%) contrast(${contrast.value}%);

Comment: хе хе, css фильтры применяются уже где нибудь на gpu,  в веб - нельзя получить к этому доступ, попробуйте html2canvas, мб там это реализовано, а вообще-то надо руками в таком случае колбасить картинку

Comment: Принял, благодарю